# Add paste item to windows right click menu in c#

Tags: c#, contextmenu, clipboard, paste

I am making an advanced clipboard program, and I managed to do the part where it remembers a list of copied items, but I need to manage that content being pasted in as well.

I tried and failed to find a way to detect a paste from the clipboard, so now I'm trying to add the copied out items to a context menu dropdown item in the Windows context menu.

So far however I only managed to find a way to add items to the `Folder` key in regedit, which doesn't help when I need to paste in text into a textbox, or notepad.

Is there a way to do that?

I'm working in C# in .NET 4.0 on a Win 8.1 x64 PC

EDIT:

My point is to gather everything that is being copied/cut to the clipboard, and then to be able to paste specific lines from that list into an editable text container. 
Either in automatically in the same/reverse order of them being copied or manually via a dropdown menu in the windows context menu, containing each line on my list.

Comment: What's wrong with using system.windows.forms.clipboard?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am using that, but that is only good for getting data. I cannot paste text from my list into notepad using that, or if I can, i don'T know how.

Comment: Did you try `SendKeys.Send("^v")`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled To be honest, I haven't and that is something I should remember for later times, but sadly not very helpful in my case. I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: `the windows context menu` is active for Explorer - any app such as an arbitrary one with an "editable text container" has the option to implement ots own menu or even one specific for the edit control

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah... I was afraid someone would tell me that. In that case i can't do much except hook the keyboard and wait for a `CTRL+V` i guess. Thanks